# Getting Key Values from user input within python dict

Tags: python, dictionary, keyvaluepair

I have hundreds of IP cameras that I have connected to an amazon ec2 instance, which performs NAT so the cameras use the Public IP of the instance and can be switched between cameras based on Port specified. I am trying to Write a simple python script that will return key values based on user input. for example, I want the user to be able to input "truck22" and based on that input be prompted for the correct port for that vehicle. Then I would like the script to open a webbrowser to the correct host and port. My Code looks like:

```
import webbrowser
import os
host = 192.168.1.1
trucks = {'truck22': ':1400', 'truck22 rear': ':1401', 'truck76': ':1412'}
for key in trucks.keys():
value = trucks.get(key)
choice = input("Select your item: ")
if choice in trucks:
webbrowser.open("http://" +host +value)
else:
print("invalid Truck number")
```

OUTPUT: webbrowser opens to 192.168.1.1:1400
The only issue am having is that it always returns the first key value of truck 22 which is port 1400, even if I enter another key name. Any Ideas?

Comment: Hi, in Python the indentation is of great significance. Could you please update your question to make the code proper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the port from the dict using `choice`

**Ex:**

```
import webbrowser
import os
host = 192.168.1.1
trucks = {'truck22': ':1400', 'truck22 rear': ':1401', 'truck76': ':1412'}

choice = input("Select your item: ")
if choice in trucks:
    webbrowser.open("http://" +host + ":" +trucks.get(choice))
else:
    print("invalid Truck number")
```

Comment: Please accept ans if it solved your problem by clicking the tick button next to the ans. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code, for loop is not necessary. You only need to check whether your input is in the dictionary.

`choice = input("Select your item: ")
if choice in trucks:
    webbrowser.open("http://" +host +trucks[choice])
else:
    print("invalid Truck number")`

Comment: Both of these answers were exactly what I was looking for. thank you!